# Use defineAsyncComponent with non-vue native web components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, custom-element, native-web-component

#### Is it possible to use `defineAsyncComponent` and dynamic `<component>` with non-vue native web components?

Let's assume I have a web component, which was created with `lit` and now I want to use it via `defineAsyncComponent` inside my `Vue` project. Something like this:

```js
const MyAsyncComponent = defineAsyncComponent(
  async () => (await import('my-native-web-component')).MyNativeWebComponent,
);
```

```html
<template>
  <component :is="MyAsyncComponent" />
</template>
```

Comment: defineAsyncComponent is for Vue components, not web. I'd expect that you can use web comps by their names with <component> if they are properly registered.

Comment: @EstusFlask Do you have a docs link, where this is explicitly stated? And how would you asynchronously load native web components in Vue?

Comment: Here https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html "use `AsyncComp` like a normal component". Web comp is not a normal comp. See https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#using-custom-elements-in-vue . I expect that it can be asynchronously imported in async setup and registered with customElements.define and it will be correctly rendered. If this doesn't suit your case, consider explaining it.